# How to convert the following line c# to Visual c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I am trying to convert my "Digit To Words" class from c# to Visual C++.  I am having trouble with the last line listed below:

```
String^ strNum;
String^ strNumDec;
String^ StrWord;
strNum = Convert::ToString(Num); // Num is Decimal Parameter
blah..blah...blah...

StrWord = ((double.Parse(strNum) == 1) ? " Rupee " : " Rupees ") + NumToWord((decimal)(double.Parse(strNum))) + ((double.Parse(strNumDec) > 0) ? (" and Paise" + cWord3((decimal)(double.Parse(strNumDec)))) : "");
```

Could you please post a Visual C++ equivalent?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Num` but convert it from `decimal` to `string` to `double`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` to convert your `Num` to string.

`char strNum[128];`
`sprintf(strNum, "%f", Num);`

To convert string to double - use `atof`